# Chess GUI Java Swings code needs fixing

Tags: engines, software

My Taken Pieces Panel clusters ugly with the pieces.[image: GUI bug]

Here's my code :

```
class TakenPiecesPanel extends JPanel {
private final JPanel northPanel;
private final JPanel southPanel;
private final Dimension TAKEN_PIECES_DIMENSION = new Dimension(80, 80);

TakenPiecesPanel(){
    super(new BorderLayout());
    this.setBorder(PANEL_BORDER);
    this.northPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 2));
    this.southPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 2));
    this.add(this.northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(this.southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setPreferredSize(TAKEN_PIECES_DIMENSION);
}

void redo(final MoveLog movelog){
    this.northPanel.removeAll();
    this.southPanel.removeAll();

    for(final Piece takenPiece: whiteTakenPieces){
            final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(BoardUtils.ICONS_PATH +
                    takenPiece.getPieceColor().toString().substring(0,1)+
                    takenPiece.toString()+".gif"));
            final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            /*This didn't work too 
            final JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ic.getImage().getScaledInstance(
                    ic.getIconWidth() - 15, ic.getIconWidth() - 15, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));*/
            this.southPanel.add(imageLabel);
            this.southPanel.add(new JLabel(icon));
    }
    validate();
}
}
```

The images are displayed in a single column and when the number exceeds the column limit, they are displayed in the adjacent column. This is when the panel gets ugly.

I'm a beginner in GUI programming. I've tried increasing the panel size but it won't work. Please help me out.

Comment: I don't know the answer (hence why it's a comment) but could you show the piece with a number of how many have been captured, e.g. Q 0 R 1 B 2 N 1 P 4?

Comment: Also, I would challenge whether the captured pieces panel needs to be displayed at all. In practical terms, what matters more are the pieces on the board, rather than off.

Comment: I think you're asking about GUI design. No need to show your code. Nobody will read it anyway.

Comment: You probably noticed that there are 4 white knights and 3 bishops in the taken panel. Fixing that might give some space, too.

Also, it looks like 2 black rooks are in the taken panel, though there's a rook in the actual game.

I suppose you could have a default icon size, and it could be defined by how many pieces are taken e.g. for up to 20, use the default, but for every 2 pieces taken you decrease it by 5%. That's just a guesstimate, but it seems like a good first step.

Comment: @Bad_Bishop I need to show the captured pieces coz its for my project. And no, I can't show how many have been captured so, I might have to start with a 0 counter and add it every time a piece has been removed.

Comment: @aschultz Your idea looks feasible but I'm a beginner in GUI programming and can't code what you just suggested.

Comment: Thank you all. Fixed it. Missed this line earlier - this.northPanel.updateUI();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GUI design is bad. I'd just do this:

```
White pawn x3
White queen x1
Black pawn x2
....
```

Draw a chess piece and add a number to it's top-right corner. It's like how iOS and Android show the number of unread SMS messages you have.

Nobody wants to count the number of pawns in your panel. Just add a number.

Comment: And to make it even simpler, you could also just display the difference of captured pieces, e.g. if white captured 3 pawns and black captured 2 pawns, white is one pawn ahead, so you'd just display one pawn for white. Similarly for the other pieces.

Comment: As a user, I'd prefer the options @user1583209 gives. However, this might create a problem with if you have 2 queens on the board, e.g. trying to display -1 queens might cause a runtime error.

Other nice touches might be to mention if bishops were opposite colors or to allow for lumping bishops/knights together.

However, I think it would be nice to allow the player an option to switch between the two views, as both have their respective virtues. I think it would be a good (nontrivial) coding exercise.

Comment: @SmallChess So the panel displays all the distinct piece types with a x0 initially?